# On element resize scroll down page

Tags: scroll, resize, infinite-scroll

I have a resizable div, but when I do resize and reach bottom of screen I can't resize more, I need to scroll down page and start resize again. My goal is to make page scroll down automatically while resizing that div.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 

div {
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 20px;  
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 300px;
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  color: blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<center>

<h1>Example of the resize: vertical; </h1>

<div>
  <p> This is the div element. </p>
  <p> To see the resizing effect, click and drag the bottom right corner of this div element. </p>
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried to do window.scrollBY, but it didn't worked for me!